# How to create a IPA file?

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, ipad, xcode4.3

How to create an IPA file? Do I need to connect my device?

I followed [this link][1]. But I still failed.. 
Now I can build my apps, but whenever I click product->archive.

**UPDATE :** finally solved. I just change from distribution to developer.

thanks to all of you guys, specially LithuThiruvathira. Thanks for your patient for telling me which one is wrong and have me to try. thanks.

Comment: you have a working provisioning profile and your bundle id is correct?

Comment: You do not need to connect your device

Comment: @Anjaly - yes, i have. but still failed.

Comment: did you made any changes in provision profile after you created and downloaded the profile.??jus download once more ..del the old profile from organizer and install new profile and run

Comment: @LithuThiruvathira - just tried it. but still failed. anyway thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: no need of device for building an ipa file...k one more check to do...is the device you are using is added in the provisioning profile device list??It should be added otherwise ipa is not gonna work..

Comment: also chk whether included the entitlements plist.And also in your build settings chk it is the code sign identity is properly set and one more thing to check is did you make  code scheme to release??otherwise its not gonna work

Comment: @LithuThiruvathira - yes, its already added in the provisioning profile device. I already can build, but whenever I click product->archive, its show like this - "No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates". the code sign is properly set. what do you mean by code scheme?

Comment: Click on the xcode toolbar button where the project title is shown...go to edit scheme...check the build configuration  is set to release.. ??Also chk the provision profile created on your certificate itself..

Comment: Just checked it. its set to release. actually what kind of problem? it is about the certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2012/01/30/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2/

Follow the steps
In this tutorial you will get the step by step procedure to create correct provisioning profile and every other thing

After following this tutorial Go to
Products ->Archive

Comment: just followed the link. but still failed. any other clue??

Answer (score 1):

First you download your certificate and provisioning profile then double click on both. after this open your project in xcode then change the Bundle Identifier to the provisioning profiles identifier. now it works fine.

Comment: i have tried it. buat now the error change into this.. "Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificate". how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a valid provisioning profile + certificate + signature for the certificate. You should setup your project as if you would run the app on a device or simulator.

I recommend to make a clean before making the ipa (command + shift + k). Then disconnect any devices, select the "iOS Device" from the simulator/device list. Open from the menu Product/Archive and wait until the X Code finishes making the archive. After this will appear a new window, press "Share...", and you should select the certificate that belongs to the provisioning profile (and be sure the 'iOS App Store Package (ipa) is selected). Press next. Will appear another window, you should enter here the title of the app. When I'm making in-house builds, usually I check the "Save for Enterprise Distribution" box, and complete the ipa file's path at the "Application URL" and add again the "Title" of the app. Press save, and you are ready!

Comment: still can't. whenever i try to click product and archive, its build failed.. is there anything wrong?

Comment: Please, check the application identifier, it's possible to be differences. First, verify what should be the app's identifier (you should see it in the project file, where you select the provisioning profile, near the name of the prov profile you see "for Application Identifiers ..."), this name should be placed in the [projectname]-Info.plist file, at the bundle identifier. Please, tell me if it works

Comment: @mollybaba- already the same. but still can't work. i'm confused with the this.